# Why does 'None' interrupt 'for' comprehension containing 'Option's?

Tags: scala

Why does function `personFromParams` return `None`?

```
  def personFromParams(p: Map[String, String]): Option[Person] =
    for {
      name <- p.get("name")
      ageStr <- p.get("age")
      age <- toInt(ageStr)
      validStr <- p.get("valid")
      valid <- toBool(validStr)
    } yield { println("personFromParams()"); new Person(name, age, valid) }

   def tryo[T](f: => T): Option[T] = try {Some(f)} catch {case _ => None}

   def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = tryo(s.toInt);
   def toBool(s: String) = tryo(JBool.parseBoolean(s))
```

If give non-number value  into `toInt`, it returns `None` for `age`, but I don't understand
why does `toInt` interrupt `for` when the exception is caught and processed in function `tryo`.

Comment: I would recommend editing the question title to be something like "Why does 'None' interrupt 'for' comprehension containing 'Option's?" I don't really think exceptions are relevant to the question. Many people consider catching general exceptions like this in for comprehensions (or map/flatMap) a code smell too. In this case it is appropriate. This is an entirely different discussion though.

Comment: OK. You are right.  I changed title of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `for` comprehension can be equivalently written like this

```
p.get("name").flatMap{
  name => p.get("age").flatMap {
    ageStr => toInt(ageStr).flatMap {
      age => p.get("valid").flatMap {
        validStr => p.get("valid").flatMap {
          validStr => toBool(validStr).map{
            valid => { println("personFromParams()"); new Person(name, age, valid) }
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the scala documentation for [Option.flatMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option):

> Returns the result of applying f to this Option's value if this Option
>   is nonempty. Returns None if this Option is empty. Slightly different
>   from map in that f is expected to return an Option (which could be
>   None).

Answer (score 2):

It does not interupt the for execution. It's just that, when scala looks for the age collection it should go over, there is no elements to go through.

Note that for yield is equivalent to map, and nested for yield is equivalent to set product then map (not totally but you get the sense). If one of the input sets is empty, the result set is also empty too, right?

To solve this you just delete the line that goes through toInt(age), and put this in the constructor arguments.

Comment: `If one of the input sets is empty, the result set is also empty too` Yes. I understood:)

Answer (score 1):

```
for { a <- Some(3) } println(a) // 3
for { a <- None } println(a)    // no output
```

This behaviour is to expected and can be explained by looking at the expression into which a `for` gets desugared by the compiler. If you run Scala with `-print` on the snippet above, you'll see that the loop gets desugared into a `forach`:

```
new Some(scala.Int.box(3)).foreach({...})
scala.None.foreach({...})
```

Since `None` represents an empty collection, there is nothing to `foreach` over.